# Objective-c overriding delegate with its descendant type

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, first-responder

I have textView in my cell and sometimes during tableView scroll some weird calls happen. System make my textView first responder. I've found these calls do unwanted behavior:

```
#0 -[UITextView canBecomeFirstResponder] ()
#1 -[UIView(Hierarchy) deferredBecomeFirstResponder] ()
#2 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _promoteDescendantToFirstResponderIfNecessary] ()
```

I can't find out why are these called, so I've tried to deal with this by extending `UITextView` and overriding `- canBecomeFirstResponder`.

Here is my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TextViewDelegate;

@interface TextView : UITextView

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TextViewDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol TextViewDelegate <UITextViewDelegate>

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder:(TextView *)textView;

@end
```

And .m:

```
#import "TextView.h"

@implementation TextView

@synthesize delegate;

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(canBecomeFirstResponder:)] ? [self.delegate canBecomeFirstResponder:self] : NO;
}

@end
```

This solution works but on the line `@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TextViewDelegate> delegate;` I've got warning and I don't know why. It says `Property type 'id<TextViewDelegate>' is incompatible with type 'id<UITextViewDelegate>' inherited from 'UITextView'`.

So why system want to make textView first responder if I do not? Why I'm getting this warning? Is there better solution than mine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure , but I suspect the warning is because the pre-compiler knows about `TextViewDelegate` but it does not know yet that this protocol is inheriting `UITextView` protocol. Just declare it above like this:

```
@class TextView;

@protocol TextViewDelegate <UITextViewDelegate>

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder:(TextView *)textView;

@end

@interface TextView : UITextView

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TextViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

But I'm not sure I understand the question.
You have a table and in one/more/each cell you have an `UITextView`, correct?
Do you want the text view to be editable?
Because you can simply set `[textView setEditable:FALSE];`

Hope this helps.

Regards,

George

Comment: I had tried to set this editable property but it also has `inputAccessoryView` so when it becomes first responder this `inputAccessoryView` shows. I just want to take control of becoming first responder on this object. Anyway, you are correct with your answer. That thing with uninformed pre-compiler is shame...